# symmetric encryption with fixed size

Tags: symmetric

What I basically need is a way to encrypt and decrypt symmetrically an ID which is a string. Both version of the ID will live and work in different domain and I need a way to switch domain without hold in memory a mapping table. My requirements are:

- both kind of IDs must be human readble (alphanumeric).
- plain IDs have fixed length
- encrypted IDs must have fixed length (not necessarily the same of plain IDs)

`abc123 ==== encrypt ====> as78ads89dfs ==== decrypt ====> abc123
23kop2 ==== encrypt ====> jfdsdfsg8dsf ==== decrypt ====> 23kop2
...`

is there any way to obtain this with some combination of encryption and encoding?

thank you all

Comment: About any normal symmetric cipher will do this for you, although you may need to rebase the result after encryption as a modern cipher will output any byte values, not just digits. This requirement seems missing from your question (and hence the answer from SEJPM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E_k$ denote any length-preserving authenticated encryption scheme, such as AES-GCM. These will usually add a fixed overhead of 12+16=28 bytes.

Now I shall assume that you know how to generate and manage keys for the above cipher and that you know how to generate nonces for the cipher.

Let $m$ be the maximal length your plaintext will ever have, in bytes. Define $m'=m+1$, this the length of the messages after encoding and the amount of data which will be fed into $E_k$.

The encoding itself is very easy: Take an $n$-byte message, append a `0x01` byte and $m-n$ `0x00` bytes. For decoding you start from the end of the message, go over all the `0x00` bytes until you hit the `0x01` byte. You throw away anything starting at (and including) the `0x01` byte.

So the overall flow would go like

```
0xBEEF     ==> encode ==> 0xBEEF010000 ==> AE-encrypt ==> nonce ||ciphertext ||tag  ==> AE-decrypt ==> 0xBEEF010000 ==> decode ==> 0xBEEF
0xDEADBEEF ==> encode ==> 0xDEADBEEF01 ==> AE-encrypt ==> nonce'||ciphertext'||tag' ==> AE-decrypt ==> 0xDEADBEEF01 ==> decode ==> 0xDEADBEEF
```

Comment: thank you SEJPM. I edited the question to better specify my requirements

Comment: @masciugo the answer stays the same, you'd just have to apply hex / base64 encoding after the encryption step and hex / base64 decoding before the decryption step.

Comment: ok. I tried with the two mode [CBC](https://gist.github.com/masciugo/00a2760c74bf8e2d31a907df962fd305) and [GCM](https://gist.github.com/masciugo/f2da780fa6404fdcedef221ba862bb1a). I like GCM because produces an encrypted ID which is shorter than CBC but I don't really like that encrypted IDs for sequential plain IDs are too similar to each other!

Comment: @masciugo .... this is because you are using GCM completely insecurely by re-using the IV across encryptions. The IV needs to be unique for each encryption for GCM to work properly (and even more so for the unauthenticated = bad CBC mode even though it hides your mistakes better).

Comment: Does this mean that I need to store the IV used during encryption along with the encrypted ID itself to be able to decrypt it later? My two ID versions need to be persistent over time and I need to pass from one to the other as needed. I guess I am missing something big..

Comment: @masciugo yes, you need to store the IV - that the *nonce* from the expression `nonce ||ciphertext ||tag` in the answer. Or for the GCM mode the IV can be implicit (like recordId), for CBC it must be random

Comment: ... and to obtain, at later time, the crypted version of a previously encrypted ID I also need to have stored the plain ID itself along with the IV. Same for the reverse path. So to go consistently back and forth I would end up to have the following tuple in the DB: (plain ID - IV - encrypted ID). At this point storing the IV would not needed anymore. Hence I am back to our old approach that consisted of storing the IDs map in the DB. I was trying to build a IDs converter system able to encrypt/decrypt on the fly without a persistence layer but seems hard! thank you all anyway

Comment: @masciugo uhm, if you use a unique IV for each encryption (ie generate it on-the-fly for the encryption operation) and store it with the encrypted ID, then you can easily recover the plain ID, no need to store it.

Comment: Ok I got it but the fact is that I use the encrypted ID in an other domain (a secret one) as regular ID (other model may refer to it in their foreign key): sometimes, from a plain ID, I need to re-obtain the related encrypted ID (the only one used for it in the past) in order to switch domain and retrieve the related and previously stored data. I cannot do this without knowing the couple (plain ID - IV)